# Pass an object to a new thread inside a loop

Tags: c#

I have a thread that make some operations on a object and sometimes I need to launch a thread that reads and modifies this object parameters.

```
//Inside my class
MyObject obj = new MyObject();

while(true) {
    //operations on object

    MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    Thread myThread = new Thread(mc.ProcessMC);
    myThread.Start(object obj);
    obj = new MyObject();
}
```

This code modify the object successively at the next loop, or the new MyObject() creates a new object in a new space of memory and the old object passed to the new thread rests unmodified?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out how it works?

Comment: Looks like a good way to bring your machine to its knees at the very least...

Comment: @Paddy is there a more powerful way?

Comment: Neither `(object obj)` is a correct way to call a method.

Comment: @IllidanS4 Should I pass parameters via the MyClass constructor?